# UITableView duplicates each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having an issue where all of the cells in the tableView are duplicated upon loading. How do I prevent this? The code follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

PoliticianDetailsD *politician =[self.politicianDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ((NSString *)[NSNull null] == politician.first_name) {

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", politician.last_name];

}
else if ((NSString *)[NSNull null] != politician.first_name) {

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", politician.first_name, politician.last_name];

}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be adding data to your datasource `politicianDetails` twice. Try `NSLog(@"Datasource %@", self.politicianDetails);` and make sure there's no duplicate. If there is, check your code that's saving data and make sure you're not adding it twice.